# Cognito throws ErrCodeNotAuthorizedException when user is already confirmed

Tags: go, amazon-cognito

Why does cognito throw `ErrCodeNotAuthorizedException "NotAuthorizedException"` when the status of the user is already confirmed when making a request to cognito to confirm the user.
The documentation specifies that `ErrCodeNotAuthorizedException` is thrown when a user is not authorized.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.ConfirmSignUp

How should we handle this case? As it would be unclear if we made a request with invalid `client secret` as it would throw the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code is the same for the unauthorized case and user already confirmed case, the only possible way to differentiate the cases is to match the `awsErr.Message()` which provides the clear description of the error.

```golang
if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
    switch awsErr.Code() {
      case cognitoidentityprovider.ErrCodeNotAuthorizedException:
        if awsErr.Message() == "User cannot be confirm. Current status is CONFIRMED" {
            log.Println("Handle user already confirmed")
        } else {
            log.Println("Handle not authorized case")
        }
      ...
      default:          
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a typo. for me the message is "User cannot be confirmed. Current status is CONFIRMED" which makes sense and looks like a typo